# Why is ircd-hybrid max nickname length 9? (hybserv)

Tags: irc, ircd-hybrid

I have installed hybrid and hybserv and configured them both to interact properly and everything is working.

The only issue I seem to have is max nickname length is only 9 and I can't find a config option to change that.

If I connect to esper my nick length can be greater than 9 so I'm assuming this is not an irc thing.

Is there anyway to set the maximum nickname length past 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the people who maintain the package and they said that the option should be available but for some reason the config doesn't contain it.

simply add max_nick_length = n; inside the serverinfo { and everything will work fine.

```
serverinfo {
  ...
  max_nick_length = 20;
  ...
};
```